# MAC Address Spoofing/Changing Software

Tags: linux, windows, mac, mac-address

What is the best MAC address changing/spoofing/editing program available for windows, mac and linux?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Mac OS X : `ifconfig <interface> ether <new mac address>`
On linux : `ifconfig <interface> hw ether <new mac address>`
On Win XP : http://devices.natetrue.com/macshift/

Comment: I am wondering,In Linux does a reboot clear the modified mac address? Or would it be saved?

Comment: It is a rare chipset that allows modified MAC addresses to be permanently saved.  At best, you can tell the OS to restore the custom MAC at boot.

Comment: @Grishanko, womble: on Red Hat based systems, the *MACADDR* setting (from /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*) can be used for this. I use it all the time :-)

Comment: The above command is temporary on most systems and will not persist across reboots. On RedHat systems, @CristianCiupitu has the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `ifconfig` to alter the MAC address, the change is not preserved (reboot). If you want the MAC to be changed permanently, you need to edit the interface's config file.

In Debian/Ubuntu this is `/etc/network/interfaces`. Add a line like `hwaddress ether 01:02:03:04:05:06` for the interface in question:

`iface eth0 inet dhcp

    hwaddress ether 01:02:03:04:05:06`

Best,
PEra

Answer (score 1):

SMAC is good on Windows (http://www.klcconsulting.net/smac/), but it isn't free.  Many network adapters in Windows can be changed manually however...

Right-click the network adapter--> Properties --> Configure --> Advanced, and then find the property called Network Address (or Locally Administered Address depending on your version of Windows).  Enter the MAC you want without dashes, and restart so that it takes effect.  Changing the option back to "Not Present" will reset the MAC to the real hardware MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

A. For Windows

If you are going to change MAC address only once or rarely, Then in windows you can do if from device manager. In device manager change properties of network card you want to change MAC address for and in settings you get option for changing MAC address. The field is not called MAC Address, it is called something else. It is blank by default. (Not having access to windows machine so cant write exact name of the field. It was probably Device Identification but not really sure.)

You have to put only 12 hex digits of mac in the field. No separator (:) or (-) is required while entering MAC. But once you enter something in it you can leave it blank later to restore original MAC. So you must note original MAC address somewhere before putting some test MAC address in that field.

In windows you can use ettercap to spoof an capture data. You can also use cain n abel to spoof and capture passwords.

B. For Linux / MAC

In Linux and MAC you can use ifconfig command with hw parameter. Read man page for more details on how to use it.

For spoofing you can install package dsniff in Linux. It has tool called arpspoof that can help in spoofing.  Ettercap is also available for Linux. So you can use that too in case you want some GUI.

Comment: On Vista the field is called "Locally Administered Address"

Comment: I think it is same on Windows too. Thanks for the name. I had completely forgotten it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't address Windows and the Mac, but under Linux, the ifconfig command would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you asked for but how about using arp to tell 
the router your new address?

```
arp -s
```

(but ifconfig is the way to go)